# JavaScript scroll event listener not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a script that animates some items on my page.  However, because of the header, nav, and banner, the points won't be seen right when the page loads.  So I want the animation to load after the user scrolls down enough to see it.  After looking up different code on this, I came up with the code below.  However, no matter what I do, I seem to get no response with the scroll event.  I even tried to test it by sending scrolling data to the console and got nothing.

```js
"use strict";

var pointsArray = document.getElementsByClassName('point');

var animatePoints = function (points) {
  function revealPoints() {
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) { // animate all 'point' classes
      points[i].style.opacity = 1;
      points[i].style.transform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
      points[i].style.msTransform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
      points[i].style.WebkitTransform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
    } // end loop
  } // end revealPoints()

  revealPoints(); // show animations
};


window.onload = function () {
  if (window.innerHeight > 950) { // if user can see it, just do the animation
    animatePoints(pointsArray);
  }

  var sellingPoints = document.getElementsByClassName('selling-points')[0];
  var scrollDistance = sellingPoints.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight + 200;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    console.log("Current offset from the top is " + sellingPoints.getBoundingClientRect().top + " pixels");
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop >= scrollDistance) {
      animatePoints(pointsArray);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Does it log the message inside the scroll event listener (`console.log("Current offset fro...`) or not?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: put an `alert("load");` inside the `window.onload` function and see if it alerts.

Comment: I put it there and nothing happened.  Am I not accessing the scroll properly?

Comment: The problem is in the load event listener. What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried both the latest version of Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I've just tested your code It's working. Check if you included the script file!

Comment: Thats strange, let me try again

Comment: I did some testing and the whole window.onload isn't working

Comment: Put an `alert("here");` after `"use strict";` and see if it alerts!

Comment: I did that just to test, and yes it appear

Comment: Just to check again can you put the alert just after this `window.onload = function () { ` like this `window.onload = function () { alert("here");`!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `window.onload` event never fires in your case.

Can you don't use `onload`? Like here https://jsfiddle.net/ovkycmem/ or with on load https://jsfiddle.net/ovkycmem/1.

But you need to be sure that other script not override `window.onload` function. So to find out what is your problem please post more code or at least not working sample.